# Factory pattern and singleton objects in VBA

Tags: vba, singleton, garbage, factory-method

I'm thinking of using factory pattern to create singleton objects in my VBA application. Up til now, the VBA program creates many instances here and there of the same class, and when done with the instances they have been deleted.

I thought about replacing the instance creation/destruction code with a call to a factory method. So I come up with this VBA code which I placed in a module.

```
Public Function MyClassA() As Object
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If a Is Nothing Then
        Set a = CreateObject("Library.ClassA")
    End If
    Set MyClassA = a

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Set a = Nothing
    MyClassA= Err.Description
End Function
```

Since VBA doesn't have garbage collection, what is the best way to delete the instance after the program quits? 
How does the caller of the factory know that it is the last to use the instance, and that it should 
delete the instance? 
What about handling errors?

Comment: Just got a tip that I could make a manual garbage collector in the factory.

Comment: To my knowledge all variables in VBA are "lost" once they get out of their scope, unless: 1) "Static" variables, whose lifetime is the module they are inside lifetime 2) "Public" variables, that can persist between the consecutive runs. For these latter I act like follows: A) limit their use to a minimum extent B) make sure that at the beginning of a "program" I call some `SetThemAll()` Sub to properly set ALL of my public variables C) make sure that before the end of a "program" I call some `ClearThemAll()` Sub to set ALL my public variables to their "zero state"

Comment: Oh dear, off by 1 error , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables

Comment: You can't return Err.Description from a function which returns Object.  And if you make `a` a static variable inside the function then you can avoid having a global `a`.  If you only have a single instance do you need to worry at all about garbage collection?

Comment: @TimWilliams You mean that since the life time of the single instance will end when the code stops, VBA will hence take care of the GC? Didn’t think of that. I thought it would leak memory, just as when you forget to release memory in C++.

Comment: VBA uses reference counting and not garbage collection: it's pretty good at cleaning up unless you create circular references (A refers to B, B refers to A)